# Como fazer update ou insert no MySQL na mesma query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query

No PostgreSQL tem como eu utilizar o `upsert`. Ele verifica se a linha já existe, se sim, faz update, caso contrário, faz insert.

No MySQL não estou conseguindo fazer isso, vi alguns falando para usar `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, porém todos os exemplos que eu vi foi informando id.

Porém eu não tenho o ID, o ID da minha tabela é gerado automaticamente a cada insert que eu faço, portanto eu não não informo esse ID no momento de fazer um insert.

Comment: Encontrei uma solução no [GitHub](https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert), talvez possa lhe ajuda @Isaias.

Comment: a sua tabela além da coluna id não tem nenhuma outra com valores únicos e exclusivos?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo tem sim, por exemplo, em uma tabela com os dados de usuário, um valor único poderia ser o email que ele usa para logar.

Se o email existir, faz update, caso contrário faz insert.

Comment: Então qual é exatamente sua dificuldade? montar esse if else?

Comment: sua `PK` é `auto_increment`?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Sim, montar o if else utilizando apenas sql puro.

No PostgreSQL, por exemplo, basta eu usar a função UPSERT, mas no MySQL não sei como fazer.

Comment: @RicardoPontual Sim

Comment: Nesse caso você não vai conseguir usar nem `insert on duplicate`(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) nem o `replace` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html). Você provavelmente vai ter de fazer um `IF` para resolver isso

Comment: Vlw, pelo jeito vai ser mais fácil fazer no código mesmo. kkk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o INSERT com ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

É só criar um INDEX único na sua tabela com os campos que você não quer que duplique. Quando for inserir um dado duplicado, o MySQL vai executar o UPDATE.
Lembrando que caso você tente inserir um dado duplicado e não coloque o ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE o MySQL retornará um erro.

Answer (score 1):

A declaração `REPLACE` funciona da seguinte forma:

- Se a nova linha ainda não existir, insere uma nova linha.
- Se a nova linha já existir, a instrução REPLACE exclui a linha antiga
  primeiro e, em seguida, insere uma nova linha. Em alguns casos, a
  instrução `REPLACE` apenas atualiza a linha existente.

Para determinar se a nova linha já existe na tabela, o MySQL usa a `PRIMARY KEY` ou `UNIQUE KEY`. Se a tabela não tiver um desses índices, a instrução `REPLACE` é equivalente à instrução `INSERT`.

Exemplo:

```
REPLACE INTO cities(id,population) VALUES(2,300000);
```

Se a linha com id 2 já existir, vai fazer um "update" na coluna population. Se ainda não existir uma linha com id 2, vai fazer um "insert".